# PuppeteerSharp error No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:Port

Tags: c#, puppeteer-sharp

I have PuppeteerSharp project and I need to save the cookies, so I use the following code:

```
browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
{
        Headless = true,
        UserDataDir = Path.Combine(".", "user-data-dir"),
});
```

I get error this error

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
> refused it 127.0.0.1:PortNumber

But when I set the Headless to false, it run without any problem. When I googled for the error message, most solutions says it about the firewall, so I turned off the firewall but nothing changes.

Comment: Have you considered using Fiddler to figure out the difference between the requests? I have seen similar issues in the past, where the headers differ depending on `Headless`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading this [issue](https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp/issues/1613), it seems that we should use absolute path with `UserDataDir`, so this works fine:

```
browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
{
    Headless = true,
    UserDataDir = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, ".local-chromium", "Win64-884014", "chrome-win", "UserData").Replace(@"\", @"\\")
});
```

But another problem appeared because browser doesn't save any cookie.
Again, some issues on github said that the browser should be closed in order to save the cookies. I tried this:

```
await page.CloseAsync();
await browser.CloseAsync();
```

But it doesn't works as expected because the browser is still running in the background. The final solution for my was this:

```
var chromes = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses().Where(x => x.ProcessName == "chrome").ToList();

foreach (var ch in chromes)
{
    try
    {
        ch.Kill();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

The above code will close all chrome browsers, so it may need some changes in order to close the current browser only.